# DataContractJsonSerializer and files where [ ] are missing

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0

I've now tried different approaches but they all seems to lead back to the same parsing problem.

If I get a callback with a Json object in it, and I try to parse it, like this:

```
var jsonSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<Jsons>));
var oAllJsons = (List<Jsons>)jsonSerializer.ReadObject(oStream);
```

Then I'll get responses where one of them will parse, the other won't.

This Json snippet wont parse:

```
{
  "summary": {
      "durationInSeconds": 2889,
      "startTimeInSeconds": 1536486220
   }
}
```

This Json snippet do parse:

```
{
  "summary": [{
      "durationInSeconds": 2889,
      "startTimeInSeconds": 1536486220
   }]
}
```

what am I missing?
Why do I have to manually add [] if they are missing, for what ever reason in the callbacks.

Both Jsons are valid thou, so why won't DataContractJsonSerializer recognize it?

Is there some sort of setting(s) I've completely missed out on in my 3 days search..

My List object looks like this:

```
[DataMember(Name = "userAccessToken")]
public string UserAccessToken { get; set; }

[DataMember(Name = "summaryId")]
public string SummaryId { get; set; }

[DataMember(Name = "summary")]
public List<ADetail_Summary> Summary = new List<ADetail_Summary>();

[DataMember(Name = "samples")]
public List<ADetail_Sample> Sample = new List<ADetail_Sample>();
```

And the summary looks like this, at least partially:

```
[DataMember(Name = "durationInSeconds")]
public int DurationInSeconds { get; set; }

[DataMember(Name = "startTimeInSeconds")]
public int StartTimeInSeconds { get; set; }

[DataMember(Name = "startTimeOffsetInSeconds")]
public int StartTimeOffsetInSeconds { get; set; }

[DataMember(Name = "activityType")]
public string ActivityType { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is because the first version is *not* valid, in the context of what you're trying to deserialize into. If you want to deserialize to a list, the the JSON must be an array of objects. Otherwise, it will fail. Simple as that. Honestly, your payloads should be standardized, whether you want one object posted or many. For a single object, you can still have an array with a single item. When you start trying to accept different formats for the same function, you're going to have issues.

However, if you insist, then, the best recommendation would be to use a `try..catch` to catch the exception thrown when the JSON is not an array, then then parse it as single object instead:

```
var jsonSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<Jsons>));
List<Jsons> oAllJsons;

try
{
    oAllJsons = (List<Jsons>)jsonSerializer.ReadObject(oStream);
}
catch (Exception) // use actual specific exception here
{
    oAllJsons = new List<Jsons> { (Jsons)jsonSerializer.ReadObject(oStream) };
}
```

Comment: I've included the List and removed the first 2 [ ] in the working snippet, they where not ment to go there.

Comment: Your class doesn't take a list for `Summary`, unless `ADetail_Summary` inherits from `List<T>`, so it honestly should be the opposite, where the array version fails, and the single object instance succeeds. Regardless, the issue is the same, and the advice above is still applicable. It doesn't matter if the JSON is *technically* valid, it must be valid according to what you're binding to. One of those formats is *not*. That means you either need to standardize, such that the other format garners a 400 error, or you have to compensate manually. That is your answer.